# About The prototype of observer pattern

Tags: design-patterns, prototype

please help me to design the prototype of the observer pattern In C# .
What Is observer pattern ?
What About prototype of the observer pattern ?
In C#.Net

Comment: Seems somewhat vague...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Observer**

**IObserver.cs**

```
namespace ObserverOPC.Observer

{

    public interface IObserver
    {
        void Notify(int t1,int t2);
    }
}
```

**Observer1.xaml.cs**

```
using ObserverOPC.Subject;

namespace ObserverOPC.Observer

{

    public partial class Observer1 : Window,IObserver
    {       
        public Observer1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Notify(int _t1, int _t2)
        {
        //get value here
        }
    }
  }
```

**Subject**

**ISubject.cs**

```
namespace ObserverOPC.Subject

{

    public interface ISubject
    {
       void Subscribe(Observer.IObserver objObserver );
       void UnSubscribe(Observer.IObserver objObserver);
       void NotifySubscribers();
    }
}
```

**OPCAPI.cs**

```
namespace ObserverOPC.Subject

{

   public interface OPCAPI
   {
       void Update();

    }
 }
```

**OPCClient.cs**

```
using ObserverOPC.Observer;

using OPCAutomation;

namespace ObserverOPC.Subject

{

    public class OPCClient:OPCAPI,ISubject

    {
    private IList<Observer.IObserver> _observers=new List<IObserver>();

    public void Update()
    {
    }

    public void Subscribe(IObserver observer)
    {
        _observers.Add(observer);
    }

    public void UnSubscribe(IObserver observer)
    {
        _observers.Remove(observer);
    }

    public void NotifySubscribers()
    {           
        foreach (IObserver s in _observers)
        {
            s.Notify(_tag1Value,_tag2Value);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using ObserverOPC.Observer;

using ObserverOPC.Subject;

namespace ObserverOPC
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    OPCClient objOpcClient= new OPCClient();
    public MainWindow()
    {


        IObserver _client1Observer=new Observer1();
        IObserver _client2Observer = new Observer2();

         //Register the Observers            
        objOpcClient.Subscribe(_client1Observer);
        objOpcClient.Subscribe(_client2Observer);          
        objOpcClient.Update();

        this.Hide();
    }
 }
 }
```